# Is there any way to view exported PBM results?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm doing some project work with policy based management in SQL Server and noticed that after I evaluate a policy, I have the option to export the results. Is there any way to *import* those results into the same viewer? I know that the format that gets saved is XML (which, in theory, I could shred), but I really like the way that the default viewer breaks down complex policies visually and shows what exactly made a given policy fail. Is there any way to import the saved results back into that viewer?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no native built-in SQL Server viewer for exported xml policy results. Even you can import xml exported policies, these two are not compatible

Perhaps you can try some 3rd party xml viewers, like [MindFusion XMLViewer](http://www.mindfusion.eu/product1.html) is